# Adding subtitle and logo

Tags: graphics, titles

How can I add subtitle in my report.
How can I add logo (graphics) after date.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\fancypagestyle{empty}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead[L]{}
  \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=12cm]{logo.jpg}}
}

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\subtitle{( ABC......(new line) Timeperiod: 10.11.-12.11.12)}
\author{(Author)}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create your own coverpage, drop the \maketitle, or renew it to something like:

```
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
        \begin{center}
            \thispagestyle{empty}
            \textsc{\LARGE }\\[2cm]
            \textsc{\Huge The Title}\\[1cm]
            \textsf{\normalsize The Subtitle}\\[1cm]

            \textsc{\LARGE\Bla Bla Bla}\\[0.075cm]
            \textsf{\small and}\\[0.15cm]
            \textsf{\large\Bla Bla}\\[1.5cm]

            \textsf{\small by}\\[1.5cm]
            \textsc{\large Ya Di Ya Di Ya}\\[0.25cm]
            \textsc{\large 1st January 1999}\\[1.75cm]
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{logo.png}  %Insert Your Image Here.
        \end{center}
    }
```

Which Creates a Coverpage like the following, when you actually call the \maketitle command.

[image: Example Output]

Comment: +1, but, please, remove the `figure` environment, which serves no purpose. An `\includegraphics` command can go anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why that was there, I copied it from some other part of one of my documents....

Answer (score 0):

Package [`scrextend`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrextend) provides extended title pages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[extendedfeature=title]{scrextend}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\subtitle{( ABC......(new line) Timeperiod: 10.11.-12.11.12)}
\author{(Author)}
\publishers{\includegraphics{example-image}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

with result:

[image]

If the first title page should be a cover page, you can add option `titlepage=firstiscover` and modify the margins of the cover page with `\coverpagetopmargin`, `\coverpagebottommargin`, `\coverpageleftmargin` and `\coverpagerightmargin`. Note, these are macros not lengths.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[extendedfeature=title,titlepage=firstiscover]{scrextend}
\usepackage{mwe}
\renewcommand*{\coverpagebottommargin}{.3\paperheight}

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\subtitle{( ABC......(new line) Timeperiod: 10.11.-12.11.12)}
\author{(Author)}
\publishers{\includegraphics{example-image}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: cover page]